# Tab through radiobuttons

Tags: jquery

The default browser behavior is such that when you tab through form elements and you get to a radiobutton's group the focus goes onto the first radio button in the group and you need to hit spacebar to select it. I need to be able to continue tabbing and going to the next radio button, even within the same group.

The following code will not only jump to the radiobutton but will also select it, how do I continue tabbing through the rest radio buttons and then on to other elements?

```
$(':input:visible').keypress(function(event) {
     if(event.keyCode == '9') { // Tab
           $(':radio').focus(function () {
                this.checked = true;
           });
     }
});
```

I am aware it's a "hack"... And yes, each element has a unique tabindex value ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the radiobuttons are focused you can select another by using the arrow-keys
**or**
try something like:

```
$('input[name="something"]').on("keypress", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == '9')
        $(this).next().focus().attr("checked", true)
});
```

hope this works & helps ;-)